# WooCommerce storefront header cart : make dropdown cart contents wider and drop to left (right-aligned)

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce storefront for my website. I'd like header cart dropdown contents to be wider and drop to left (right-aligned). Since my header cart is at the top right corner of the screen, half the dropdown cart contents disappear into the right side of the screen. How can I make the cart contents drop to the left?

I tried the following:

CSS:

```
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    font-size: .875em;
    left: -999em;
    display: block;
}
```

My changes:

```
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 999999;
    font-size: .875em;
    left: -999em;
    display: block;
        right: 0;
}
```

but to no avail. Still half the cart contents aren't showing as in the below screenshot.

[image: header cart contents dropdown]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your css no need for the position absolute its positioning already exists

```
.site-header-cart.focus .widget_shopping_cart, .site-header-cart:hover .widget_shopping_cart {
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

this is the standard css for the storefront mini cart as you will see the left is set to 0 meaning it will always go off the left edge of the top

item so to adjust -minus the left to position like

```
   .site-header-cart.focus .widget_shopping_cart, .site-header-cart:hover .widget_shopping_cart {
        left: -120px;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Brad Holmes, perfect! wasted hours just for a line of CSS code! Thank you very much.